# Combining Observables that may have EMPTY values

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a trouble using Observables (I haven't expercience with Observables).

The scenario is:

- I have a complex object that I need to fill using HTTP service.
- Each property in this object doesn't depends on another.
- The service can return empty value.

After several unsuccessful attempts I get the following code:

My component:

```js
  startForm() {
    // En primer lugar construyo un formulario.
    this.buildForm(new Usuario());

    // Si es una recuperación, cargo sus detalles; si no los creo de nuevos.
    if (this.mailUsuario) {
      this.usuario = this.usuariosService
        .getUsuarioFromMail(this.mailUsuario)
        .pipe(switchMap(user => this.usuariosService.processUsuarioObservable(user)))
        .pipe(tap(usuario => this.userForm.patchValue(usuario)));

      this.usuario.subscribe(finalUser => {
        this.mapUser(finalUser);
      }, () => {
      }, () => this.logService.info('COMPLETE =>'));

    } else {
      this.startNewUserForm();
    }
  }
```

My service:

```js
  processUsuarioObservable(usuario: Usuario): Observable<Usuario> {
    const curriculum: Observable<Fichero>[] = usuario.curriculum.map(fichero => this.ficheroService.processFileUrl(fichero));
    const curriculumForkJoin: Observable<Fichero[]> = forkJoin(curriculum).pipe(map(fichero => fichero));
    const fotoPerfil: Observable<Fichero> = this.ficheroService.processFileUrl(usuario.fotoPerfil);

    return zip(fotoPerfil, curriculumForkJoin)
      .pipe(tap(vb => this.log.info('forkJoin' + JSON.stringify(vb))))
      .pipe(map(result => {
        const finalUser = usuario;
        finalUser.fotoPerfil = result[0];
        finalUser.curriculum = result [1];
        // finalUser.ficheros = result[2];
        return finalUser;
      }));
  }
```

And finally the file's service

```js
  getFileSrcUrl(fileKey: String): Observable<UrlModel> {
    return fileKey ? this.api.get(`${EndPoints.FICHEROS}/${fileKey}/url`) : EMPTY;
  }

  /// ...
  
  processFileUrl(fichero: Fichero): Observable<Fichero> {
    return this.getFileSrcUrl(fichero.awsKey)
      .pipe(map(urlModel => {
        fichero.urls = urlModel;
        return fichero;
      }));
  }
```

The problem is that when de latest call returns an `EMPTY` my subscription doesn't work.

I think that my problem is the operators that I choice for my `processUsuarioObservable` method but I cannot find in the docs the correct way.

Can anyone help me?

(I'm also learning English)

Answer (score 0):

replace EMPTY with something like of(null) or whatever an appropriate default value might be

```
  getFileSrcUrl(fileKey: String): Observable<UrlModel> {
    return fileKey ? this.api.get(`${EndPoints.FICHEROS}/${fileKey}/url`) : of(null);
  }


  processFileUrl(fichero: Fichero): Observable<Fichero> {
    return this.getFileSrcUrl(fichero.awsKey)
      .pipe(map(urlModel => {
        if (urlModel) // depends on what you think urls should be in the empty case? maybe an empty array?
          fichero.urls = urlModel;
        return fichero;
      }));
  }
```

or if you actually want these things excluded, filter them out beforehand:

```
const curriculum: Observable<Fichero>[] = usuario.curriculum.filter(f => !!f.awsKey).map(fichero => this.ficheroService.processFileUrl(fichero));
```

empty values will block forkJoin from emitting, all observables in a forkJoin must emit a value and complete.

Comment: You need to figure out what’s blocking your chain by adding more logging then